# EF7 projection doesnt eager load collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When selecting entities with "include" all my items gets fetched with a single SQL join statement. But when i project it to some other form with its children, the join is no longer executed, instead a separate query per row is executed to get the children. How can i prevent this? My goal is to reduce the columns fetched, and to reduce the amount of queries

This issue leads me to believe that this should work: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/599

```
//executes ONE query as expected
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ToList();

//executes MULTIPLE queries
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).Select(p => new {
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    Children = p.Children.Select(c => new {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name
    })
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing multiple queries sent to the database because EF Core is not yet smart enough to translate navigations in a projection to a JOIN. Here is the issue tracking this feature - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4007.

BTW as previously mentioned by others, Include only works when the entity type if part of the result (i.e. it means "if you end up creating instances of the entity type then make sure this navigation property is populated").

Comment: Thank you for the response, and for all the awesome work on EF! Does this mean that the children in my projection will have to be "full" child entities in the end? In other words: Is or will there be any solution where one query is executed and not more data than the projection needs (in my original question) is transferred?

Comment: Assignees: No one assigned. Opened `Dec 8, 2015`. OK I'm officially done with EFCore now. I know it is a HUGE project but I just can't justify using it any more with features like this still absent :-(

Comment: I found a good channel9 video about projections but they had a 1-1 relationship so skirted around this issue https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-60-Projections-with-Entity-Framework-Core#comments. My problem is that my main entity represents an email with the full html body - so loading everything is out of the question :-( I might be able to use a view as a fake table and load the full entity

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
Children = p.Children.Select(c => new {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name
    })
```

eager loading statement `Include()` work only with requests without projections.

instead of this you can do:

```
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).AsEnumerable()
.Select(p => new {
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    Children = p.Children.Select(c => new {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name
    })
}).ToList();
```

AsEnumerable() says to EF that all code after it should be executed on objects and should not be transfered to sql requests.

Comment: Doesnt the link i provided to github explain that it actually should work with include+projections? Im not sure how to interpret it. While your solution cuts down the number of queries to two, it does fetch all the columns for all entities involved. (so the projection is correct, but lots of data is transferred)

Answer (score 2):

This is partially fixed for EFCore 2.0.0-preview2 (currently not on nuget)

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/0075cb7c831bb3618bee4a84c9bfa86a499ddc6c

> This is partially addressed by [#8584](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8584) - if the collection navigation is
>   not composed on, we re-use include pipeline which creates 2 queries,
>   rather than N+1. If the collection is filtered however, we still use
>   the old rewrite and N+1 queries are being issued

I don't know exactly what `composed on` means here and if it just means that the `Child` object cannot be filtered (probably acceptable for most cases), but my guess is that certainly your original query as it stands would now work.

Comment: thanks for following up on this. For other readers: theres a disscussion here with a example on how to project inclusions with one query: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4007#issuecomment-311224545