# Empty Linq Query with null values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

My project is using EF7-RC1. My query should return a list of anonymous types however if a value is null the result will be empty.

I've tried to fix this problem with the following:

```
            var testQuery = (from com in db.Complaints
                select new
                {
                    ComplaintName = com.ComplaintName,
                    ProjectName = com.Project.ProjectName,
                    RemarkClient = com.RemarkClientNavigation != null ? com.RemarkClientNavigation.RemarkText : "n/a",
                    RemarkArchitect = com.RemarkArchitectNavigation != null ? com.RemarkArchitectNavigation.RemarkText : "n/a",
                }).ToList();
```

I've also tried using .DefaultIfEmpty() and a null coalescing operator, however the query result will still return empty.

How can I get my query to return results even if the value is null?

Comment: I don't see any issue with query, do you have data in db?

Comment: @HariPrasad Yes I do. I wonder if this is a problem with EF7.

Comment: @Travis could you try to fetch like this `db.Complaints.Include(RemarkClientNavigation).ThenInclude(RemarkArchitectNavigation).ToList()` try this without projecting to anonymous

Comment: @Eldho This does not work either. I've re-created my original query under EF6 and it works. This seems to be an EF7 issue.

Comment: I believe this should be worked, i had used this before in ef 7.pls add issue  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new

Comment: @Eldho This is the query I wrote: 
`var query = db.Complaints
.Include(b => b.RemarkClientNavigation).ThenInclude(b => b.RemarkText).ToList();`
The error I get back is "Value cannot be null" am I doing something wrong here? I want to be sure before I submit an Issue to GitHub.

Comment: try this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1768 also this so question and note the first line is executed as expected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316939/ef7-projection-doesnt-eager-load-collections

Comment: @Eldho Looks like I may have to wait for EF7 to implement this.